# Как составить подобный запрос oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

Помогите составить такой sql запрос - 
Вывести список названий языков, за исключением тех, что разработаны первой или последней (задавать с помощью параметра) по алфавиту фирмой. Структура БД такая:

```
N | ТИП | ЯЗЫК | ФИРМА
```

Мой запрос получился следующий:

```sql
SELECT lang FROM table WHERE lang NOT IN 
(SELECT lang FROM table WHERE company ??? ORDER BY company ASC);
```

Comment: Укажите, что вы сами сделали для решения этой задачи и что конкретно не получилось

Comment: Исправил, получился примерно такой запрос, понятия не имею, что использовать взамен ???)

Comment: Отзываю закрытие. надо подумать, довольно сложно сходу сформулировать правильный запрос, он довольно витиеватый получится на оракле

Comment: Вот и я уже час бьюсь, если чего получится, дайте знать)

Comment: Поправил ответ на полное соответствие задачи, надеюсь я правильно понял вопрос

Comment: Спасибо за предоставленное решение, но оно немного не подходит) Допустим, у меня есть, например, язык, который разрабатывался двумя компаниями, и в результирующий запрос он попадает, хотя не должен.

Comment: Готово. Думаю сейчас ответ должен полностью отвечать условиям задачи

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получилось как то так ...

```
select distinct lang from test1
 where lang not in
  (select lang from test1 t
    where company in(
                  select decode(?,1,min(company),max(company)) from test1
                 )
  )
```

Если '?' = 1 - то выберется кроме минимальной компании, другое числовое значение '?' - максимальной

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT lang FROM table WHERE lang NOT IN 
(SELECT decode(:param,'max',max(lang),'min',min(lang) FROM table );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT lang FROM table WHERE lang NOT IN 
(
select * from (
    SELECT min(lang) FROM table 
    where :param='min'
    order by company
    )

union all 

select * from (
    SELECT max(lang) FROM table 
    where :param='max'
    order by company
    )
)
```